# How to programmatically display "Send a Calendar via E-mail" dialog with VSTO?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I need to programmatically show the "Send a Calendar via E-mail" dialog with C#. ForwardAsICal seemed like the way to go, but that directly attaches the .ics file into your MailItem. I need the user to select the calendar details themselves. I cannot seem to find the correct command to trigger that dialog prompt. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found my answer with the deprecated CommandBars. Did not know it was still used for execute.

`OutlookApp.ActiveInspector().CommandBars.ExecuteMso("CalendarInsert");` was what I needed.